# Pandas parse integers separated by commas and colons in a series

Tags: python, pandas

Question is very similar to: 
[Pandas sum integers separeted by commas in a string column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947781/pandas-sum-integers-separeted-by-commas-in-a-string-column)

Solution: `df['B'].apply(lambda x: sum(map(int, x.split(','))))`

Except the series has colons in string and would like to do it as a vector.

```
    A      B                                                        
0   1      0                                                        
1   2    3,1::4                                                        
2   3      1                                                        
3   4      3                                                        
4   5  2,1,2::5                                                        
5   6    2,1                                                        
6   7      0                                                        
7   8      0                                                        
8   9      0                                                        
9  10  4,3,1::8
```

I am trying to split on  `('::')` and use 0th, then 
add 0th elements which are separated by `","`

```
0    0                                                              
1    4                                                              
2    1                                                              
3    3                                                              
4    5                                                              
5    3                                                              
6    0                                                              
7    0                                                              
8    0                                                              
9    8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with..... 
would like to do second line as vector

```
dd = dd.str.split("::").str[0]

dd.apply(lambda x: sum(map(int, x.split(','))))
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Setup

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

text = """    A      B                                                        
0   1      0                                                        
1   2    3,1::4                                                        
2   3      1                                                        
3   4      3                                                        
4   5  2,1,2::5                                                        
5   6    2,1                                                        
6   7      0                                                        
7   8      0                                                        
8   9      0                                                        
9  10  4,3,1::8"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), delim_whitespace=True, index_col=0)
```

#### Solution

```
import re

def split_dbl_cln_sum_thingy(x):
    # remove :: and anything after
    # () captures whats inside as \1
    # ? tells the * operator not to be greedy
    x = re.sub(r'(.*?)::.*', r'\1', x)
    # split on commas, turn to ints, and sum up
    x = sum([int(i) for i in x.split(',')])
    return x

df.B.apply(split_dbl_cln_sum_thingy)
```

#### Demonstration

```
print df.B.apply(split_dbl_cln_sum_thingy)

0    0
1    4
2    1
3    3
4    5
5    3
6    0
7    0
8    0
9    8
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need some sort of a regular expression to get the right digits. This one:

```
pattern = r'(?<!:)\d+'
```

[matches](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html) all digits that are not preceded by a colon. So you can concatenate it with `apply`:

```
df['B'].str.findall(pattern).apply(lambda x : np.sum(list(map(int,x))))
```